# 400 Bad Request when sending XHR from React.js to admin-ajax.php

Tags: ajax, network-admin

I'm trying to send ajax requests from a React.js app to wordpress's admin-ajax.php. Here is a mini test plugin I wrote to test this:

```
// plugins folder > xhrLink/xhrLink.php
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Xhr Link
*/

function basicPage() {
  echo "<h1>Admin Page</h1>";
}

function setupParams() {
  add_options_page('XHR Link', 'XHR Link', 'manage_options', 'xhr-link',  'basicPage');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'setupParams');


function handleXhrLink() {
  wp_send_json('this response came from the back end');
}
add_action('wp_ajax_xhrLink', 'handleXhrLink');


// theme folder > functions.php
function add_cors_http_header() {
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');
```

In the React.js app I have the following function set to fire on the onClick attribute of a  button:

```
const sendXhrLinkRequest = () => {
      let form_data = new FormData;
      form_data.append('action', 'xhrLink');

      axios
        .post('http://localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', form_data)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response, `=====sendXhrLinkRequest response=====`);
      });

  };
```

From [WordPress AJAX with Axios](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/282163/wordpress-ajax-with-axios):

> FormData interface provides a way to easily construct a set of
>   key/value pairs representing form fields and their values, which can
>   then be easily sent using the XMLHttpRequest.send() method. It uses
>   the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to
>   "multipart/form-data".

After clicking the button the Chrome console shows this:

```
VM596:1 POST http://localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)
(anonymous) @ VM596:1

VM596:1 XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php".

createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:59)
```

Does anyone know what causes these errors and how to handle them?

Also tried:

- Submitting the form data as a JSON object. Same console entries resulted.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by adding an action to handle unauthenticated users:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_xhrLink', 'handleXhrLink');
```